# Accidentally removed cron hourly

Tags: cron, webmin

I have a computer running ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I accidentally deleted cron.hourly files in Webmin. But very strangely, when i run

```
cd /etc/cron.hourly
ls
```

My entries (php, apache2, man-db...) still appear. I tried rebooting my PC and this entries still does not show in webmin. Who should I trust ?

I am also worried about the fact that Webmin could have deleted some entries and kept other one.
Would it be a good idea to simply reinstall cron ? If I do this, will I have to manually rewrite cron.hourly ; cron.daily... ?

Sorry for my english

I hope my question was clear

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 0):

ement05,

cron does not seem to be your problem here but anacron -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron <- It's anacron that runs your scripts in /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily etc. Maybe check webmin for it? And take a look at your /etc/crontab. If I'm right it should be quite empty.

BUT: Afaik, Ubuntu doesn't support webmin anymore and shouldn't be used as it may corrupt system files -> https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/Webmin/ <- (last update: Oct 19th, 2019). You may wanna check for its compatibility again.

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: Well I don't think anacron is my problem since Anacron just runs what is in the cron directories. My crontab is not empty :
```47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )                    

52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

And the anacron task is also in the cron daily and cron weelky folder.
I installed Webmin using the deb package on their site. I know this this tool is very "dangerous" since they are many important actions (like delete cron ;) that does

Comment: Show you a confirmation but I prefer using a frienly UI like Webmin instead of SSH !

Answer (score 0):

Previously existed cron entries may be got with command

```
dpkg -S /etc/cron.hourly
```

Then you can reinstall them with command like (check exact package list from previous command)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cron
```

---

References:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html

Comment: Thanks the first command worked but when I run the second command, apt tells me that :"Command line option --force-confask is not understood in combination with the other options"
And, if I reinstall cron, will I have to write manually the entries in cron.daily directory or will this be automatic ?

Comment: How many entries you have with "`dpkg -S /etc/cron.hourly`" ?

Comment: I have problem with both cron hourly and cron daily. I got quite a few actually so I guess that it is not broken :

cron, fake-hwclock: /etc/cron.hourly |||

apt-show-versions, mdadm, samba, anacron, cron, apache2, dpkg, man-db, passwd, bsdmainutils, logrotate, apt, quota: /etc/cron.daily

So is everything ok ?